# Audio on Android works normally, but when I play it on ios it gives this error knowing that the audio url is from firebase

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, just-audio

error :
flutter: (-11828) Cannot Open
flutter:
#0 AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:840:9)

#1 AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1421:28)

#2 AudioPlayer.play (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:914:28)

the code :

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class AudioExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioExample> createState() => _AudioExampleState();
}

class _AudioExampleState extends State<AudioExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final session = await AudioSession.instance;
                await session
                    .configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
                final player = AudioPlayer();
                final duration = await player.setUrl('audio link');

                player.play();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solved the problem? i'm facing exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

In info.plist add

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>... explain why the app uses the microphone here ...</string>
```

and in pod file add

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    
    # ADD THE NEXT SECTION
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
        'AUDIO_SESSION_MICROPHONE=0'
      ]
    end
    
  end
end
```

then run pod install and try again

Comment: Same error I was putting all these instructions